# Jenkins And Launch Safari With Extensions

Tags: bash, selenium, jenkins, safari

I'm running into issues where Jenkins will not launch safari with the installed extensions. When i take the same bash script and execute it via terminal (outside of jenkins) the script runs as expect.

The extension having issues is the Selenium Web Driver Safari Extension. 
When Safari loads i'm presented with prompt that the Extension has been migrated. All automated UI tests then fail of course.

I've google searched for my answer and browse stackoverlfow, but i can't figure it out.

1. I have the certificate from apple dev applied on the system folder of my key chain
2. The 2.45 Safari extension is installed and function
3. the webdriver is instantiated with safari_opts.skip_extension_installation = true

   - OSX - 10.10.2
   - Jenkins - 1.606
   - Safari - 8.04

I'm struggling to figure out the problem. Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: Jenkins is running everything in a "clean" environent, without any ENV variables etc etc The question is - are the keychains applied within that session? Copuld you try to do it as a build step?

Comment: @Stanjer are you suggesting that happen with the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin or is there another way to do that?

Comment: something like security -v unlock-keychain -p <pass> ~/login.keychain   PS I mean I havent tried that plugin, so don't know how and if it works :)

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer, not comment.  That fixed my problem @Stanjer! I'd like to vote it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jenkins is running a job in a clean environment, even if you have already added a keychain, it will ignore it. So, you should add a keychain as a build step. Something like:

```
security -v unlock-keychain -p <pass> ~/login.keychain
```

Answer (score 0):

yup, stanjer is right... i just add this answer to improve it.

go detail of this issue specially comment no " 71" .

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7933

I use this code at the beginning of my shell script like below:

```
keychain="~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
security -v unlock-keychain -p ewew1221 ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain 

if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
 echo "Cannot open keychain ${keychain}"
 exit 1
fi
```

ewew1221 is my password